# Dictionaries as argument in numba

Tags: python, dictionary, numba

I'm working on a part of a code for which I'm using numba. The functions are defined with dictionaries as an argument. The idea behind this code is to do an integration of a function by for instance trapz rule using numba and saves the result in a new category of the dictionary. Here is my attempt

```
from functools import partial
import ctypes
from numba import jit, prange,cfunc, carray
from numba.types import float64, CPointer, void, intp
from numba import njit
from numba import typed, typeof
from numba.experimental import jitclass 

def set_variables():
# initialization of parameters 
    Var = {}
    x_0, x_1,n = 0,1,4000
    A = 1.2
    Var['xvec'] = linspace(x_0,x_1,n)
    Var['bool'] = True
    Var['Amplitude'] = A
    return Var

@jit 
def myfun (x,Var):
#test function
    if Var['bool']:
        A = Var['Amplitude']
        return A*x**x
    else :
        return x**x

@jit(nopython=True, parallel=True)
def parallel_sum3(xvec,Var,fun):
#trapz rule with numba
    
    Y_0,Y_1 = fun(xvec[0],Var),fun(xvec[1], Var)
    
    h = xvec[1]-xvec[0]
    sum_f = .5*(Y_0+Y_1)*h
    sum = .0
    for i in prange(1,xvec.shape[0]):
        sum +=fun(xvec[i],Var)
    sum_f += sum*h 
    return sum_f

def print_result(Var):
# get result and save  in Var    
    xvec = Var['xvec']
    A = parallel_sum3(xvec,Var,myfun)
    Var['result'] = A
    return A
```

My goal is to have a function that performs the integration on parallel and reads and writtes on `Var` which may have different classes as integers, floats, array, booleans, etc. So far this code gives me an error when I want to do

```
Var = set_variables
print_result(Var)
```

which is the following

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-61-d2f49038d612>", line 1, in <module>
    T = printeo3(Var)

  File "/scratch/dgresta/Four terminals/numba_test.py", line 82, in printeo3
    A = parallel_sum3(xvec,Var,myfun)

  File "/home/dgresta/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py", line 468, in _compile_for_args
    error_rewrite(e, 'typing')

  File "/home/dgresta/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py", line 409, in error_rewrite
    raise e.with_traceback(None)

TypingError: non-precise type pyobject
During: typing of argument at /scratch/dgresta/Four terminals/numba_test.py (69)
```

I'm using python 3.9.1 and numba 0.55.1
Any guess on how to get rid off this error?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

This is **not supported by Numba** (and will certainly not be in the future). Indeed, the [documentation](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/pysupported.html#typed-dict) explicitly states:

> Numba does not fully support the Python `dict` because it is an *untyped* container that can have any Python types as members. To generate efficient machine code, Numba needs the keys and the values of the dictionary to have fixed types, *declared in advance*. To achieve this, Numba has a *typed* dictionary, `numba.typed.Dict`, for which the *type-inference* mechanism must be able to infer the key-value types by use, or the user must explicitly declare the key-value type using the `Dict.empty()` constructor method.

In your case, you cannot specify a precise type that would work for a Numba typed-dict. Thus, you need to split the dictionary in multiple ones so the type of each is well defined for Numba. Regarding your code, it is probable better not to use dictionary but to *just use simple variables*.

Comment: In my larger code my dictionary has several variables inside it which is common though all the functions in my program, that's why I 'm not using simple variables. Is there any way to make a sort of automatic translation between the python class dictionary and numba one?

Comment: AFAIK there is no such tool, and even if it exists, then it will not be so great to use since you need at least a variable per dictionary-type. In your case this means 3 variables. Note that they can be wrapped in a [JIT-class](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/jitclass.html) (which is an experimental feature of Numba). Keep in mind that lists and dict must be *typed* and are *owned&copied* by Numba. I think it should be much better than using dictionaries since they are not the right tool here and appear to be static ones. I do not see other options.